# Sabre: Exception Handling in EnhancedAirBook

Tags: sabre

Sometimes I come across this response while processing EnhancedAirBook

```
<Message code="ERR.SP.PROVIDER_TIMEOUT">No response from service provider in time</Message>
```

So how can I handle this exception, does this mean I need to discard the process and start again from BargainFinderMax Search?

Also I would like to know is there any document stating possible Exceptions/Errors/Warnings of Sabre Methods?

Answer (score 1):

Are you testing against CERT environment?
It can be an intermittent issue.

For common errors with EAB, you can check the Orchestrated Sabre APIs user guide under:

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/book/orchestrated_air_booking/resources

Comment: Hi yes, am testing the Workflow in CERT mode. So is there any documents which guides me on such exceptions?

Comment: Here's a guide on status and error codes:
https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_basics/status_codes_and_errors

Do you keep getting errors now?